# Exclude Appendix sections in toc but keep list of appendices

Tags: table-of-contents, appendix

I know this is a common problem, but none of the questions I read answered my own problem. So, after hours (days?) of trying, I need to ask you myself.

I have used the appendix package to create my appendix in an article document (it's my master's thesis). I finally managed to create a List of Appendices. Here's my code so far:

**The preamble:**

```
\documentclass[12pt, appendixprefix=true]{article} 

% Sprache (english oder ngerman)
\usepackage[australian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

% Schriftart
\usepackage{mathpazo}

% Seitenformatierung und Abstände
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=4cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=2cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\parskip}{0mm}


% Fußnoten und Kopfzeile
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark} % set the left-hand side of the header to the current section
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage} % set the right-hand side of the header to the current page

% Pagestyle für Anhang
\fancypagestyle{appendices}{
    \fancyhf{} % Clear default header/footer
    \fancyhead[L]{APPENDIX} % Set left header
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage} % Set right header
}

[Many other packages and settings for the rest of the document]

% Biblatex
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
citestyle=authoryear,                   % Zitieren im Text      
bibstyle=authoryear,                    % Literaturverzeichnis Anzeige
giveninits=true,                        % Vornamen abkürzen
maxbibnames=3,                          % Nach 3 Autoren -> et al.
sorting=nyt,                            % Nach Name, Titel, Jahr
isbn=false,                             % ISBN nicht mit angeben
doi=true,
dashed=false]                              % DOI nicht mit angeben
{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}


% Appendix
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Beginn des Dokuments
\begin{document}

% Titelseite
\input{Masterarbeit/Titelseite.tex}
\pagenumbering{Roman} % Römische Zahlen vor Hauptteil

% Gliederung
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

% Einleitung
\pagenumbering{arabic} % Arabische Zahlen ab Kapitel 1
\pagestyle{fancy}
\input{Masterarbeit/1. Einleitung.tex}
[etc.]

% Literaturverzeichnis
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\printbibliography
\clearpage
    
% Anhang
\appendix
\input{Masterarbeit/9. Appendix.tex}
\clearpage

% Ende des Dokuments
\end{document}
```

**And then this is the code in my appendix**:

```
% Only "Appendix" in TOC
% \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}

\pagestyle{appendices}
% Appendixverzeichnis
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{\Large Appendix}
\appendixpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}
\startcontents[sections]
\printcontents[sections]{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{fancy}

% Leitfaden Deutsch
\includepdf[ %erste Seite
offset= 1cm -1.5cm, 
width=\dimexpr\textwidth, 
pages=1, 
trim=0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm, 
clip, 
frame=true,
pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}
\section{Interview Guidelines}
\subsection{German Guideline}}
]{Masterarbeit/Bilder/Leitfaden_de}
\includepdf[ % weitere Seiten
offset=1cm 0cm, 
width=\dimexpr\textwidth, 
pages=2-4, 
frame=true,
pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}]{Masterarbeit/Bilder/Leitfaden_de}

% Leitfaden Englisch
\includepdf[ %erste Seite
offset= 1cm 0cm, 
width=\dimexpr\textwidth, 
pages=1, 
trim=0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm, 
clip, 
frame=true,
pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}\subsection{English Guideline}}]{Masterarbeit/Bilder/Leitfaden_eng}
\includepdf[ % weitere Seiten
offset=1cm 0cm, 
width=\dimexpr\textwidth, 
pages=2-4, 
frame=true,
pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}]{Masterarbeit/Bilder/Leitfaden_eng}
```

Now, I have a nice list of appendices appearing at the `\appendixpage` command.
However, the sections and subsections still appear in my table of contents. I want it to stop after "Appendix".

I can use the `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}` command, then it stops after "Appendix". But in that case, it also stops generating my list of appendices at the `\appendixpage`.

Here are some screenshots:
[image]
[image]

What do I need to change please?

Comment: I haven't gotten your code to compile even while substituting/commenting out the inputs.

Comment: Does this link help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214131/exclude-appendix-sections-subsections-and-subsubsection-from-toc

Comment: You say that this is a common problem, but I haven't come across it before. Any chance of identifying where you have seen it before?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answers so far. When I say common problem, I refer to the one you posted, user23456234 and this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214131/exclude-appendix-sections-subsections-and-subsubsection-from-toc

Anyways, what I want is:
In the table of content, it should read "Appendix......page"
And then, when I go to the first page of the appendix, there should be a list of appendices (like a second table of contents), where all the sections and subsections of the appendix are listed.

Comment: So far, there's only these two options:
1. I get a list of appendices. But the sections and subsections are ALSO portrayed in the table of contents. 

2. When I use \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}} , to exclude the appendice's sections from the table of contents, it doesn't do the list of appendices at the end anymore.

Comment: I'd also be open to use a different solution, like creating a second table of contents altogether, but it somehow doesn't work with my code.

Comment: Hi @kfur23 have you had any chance to achieve this?